# Excel preview from BI Publisher plug in opens wrong file

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher, xml-publisher

I have an Excel based template for XML Publisher.  When I go to preview the report it opens a completely different template file.  I have tried removing the default Excel template but it makes no difference.  Clearly something is confused.  How is this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the wrong template file is opened in Excel, go to File -> Open File Location (under Related Documents).

For me, this navigates to .\%APPDATA%\Local\Oracle\BIPublisher\TemplateBuilderforExcel\tmp.  Delete or rename the .xls files in this folder.  Then open the next tmp folder and delete or rename the .xls file in this folder as well.

After clearing out these files, retest the issue.  Should be resolved.